# How to update an existing exchange rate

Tags: c#, axapta, dynamics-ax-2012

Using the `ExchangeRateServiceClient` every time I try to use `client.create` for currency a currency code pair I get an exception

> Cannot create a record in Exchange rate currency pair (ExchangeRateCurrencyPair). From currency: USD, EUR. The record already exists.
>   System.Exception {System.ServiceModel.FaultException}

I am brand new to the AX API...I am using C#

```
AXDev09.ExchangeRateServiceCreateRequest request = 
new AXDev09.ExchangeRateServiceCreateRequest();
AXDev09.ExchangeRateServiceClient client = new AXDev09.ExchangeRateServiceClient();

request.CallContext = new AXDev09.CallContext();
request.CallContext.Language = "en-us";
request.CallContext.Company = "T51";
request.CallContext.MessageId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

AXDev09.AxdEntity_CurrencyPair[] myPair = new AXDev09.AxdEntity_CurrencyPair[1];
myPair[0] = new AXDev09.AxdEntity_CurrencyPair();
myPair[0].ToCurrencyCode = "EUR";  
myPair[0].FromCurrencyCode = "USD";

AXDev09.AxdEntity_ExchangeRate[] myExchange = new AXDev09.AxdEntity_ExchangeRate[1];
myExchange[0] = new AXDev09.AxdEntity_ExchangeRate();
myExchange[0].ExchangeRate = Convert.ToDecimal("0.708");
myExchange[0].ExchangeRateSpecified = true;

myPair[0].ExchangeRate = myExchange;
myPair[0].ExchangeRateDisplayFactor = AXDev09.AxdEnum_ExchangeRateDisplayFactor.One;
myPair[0].ExchangeRateType = "Average";

AxdType_DateTime myFromDate = new AxdType_DateTime();
myFromDate.localDateTime = DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime();
myFromDate.timezone = AxdEnum_Timezone.GMTMINUS0600CENTRALTIME;
myFromDate.Value = myFromDate.localDateTime;

AxdType_DateTime myToDate = new AxdType_DateTime();
myToDate.localDateTime = DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime();
myToDate.timezone = AxdEnum_Timezone.GMTMINUS0600CENTRALTIME;
myToDate.Value = myToDate.localDateTime;

request.LedgerExchangeRate = new AXDev09.AxdLedgerExchangeRate();
request.LedgerExchangeRate.CurrencyPair = myPair;
request.LedgerExchangeRate.ValidFromDateTime = myFromDate;
request.LedgerExchangeRate.ValidToDateTime = myToDate;

client.Open();

client.create(request.CallContext, request.LedgerExchangeRate);
client.Close();
```

Answer (score 0):

The `ExchangeRateServiceClient` does appear to be a standard API.

The standards web service is called `LedgerExchangeRateService`.

If you provide two currencies, then try to reverse them.

Comment: Thank you for your answer...what I'm trying to do is update an existing ExchangeRateCurrencyPair with a new Exchange Rate (0.708)...

Comment: This is an class created for our company using abstracts of the AX Class Libraries, so I don't think we can instantiate them directly...I was looking at the AX libraries on TechNet and there is and Update method. So I need that? I assumed you can create a new exchange pair with a different From-To date pair so that is why I am trying to Create.

Comment: Sorry but this is incomprehensible, show your code in the question, remember to mark as code to make it readable. Then delete your comments.

Comment: I get a "Creation has been canceled." when I try reversing...I was able to create a new Pair for GBP EUR. I just can't seem to update an existing Pair.

Comment: I am trying to add a new currency rate...with a new set from from-to but I keep getting "The record already exists" error eventhough I'm setting new FROM-TO dates.

Answer (score 0):

if the error message is to be believed, seems like the issue is when it tries to create the ExchangeRateCurrencyPair

there is a no-duplicates index on:

- fromCurrency
- toCurrency
- ExchangeRateType

"I am trying to add a new currency rate...with a new set from from-to but I keep getting "The record already exists" error eventhough I'm setting new FROM-TO dates."

it seems to be objecting to ExchangeRateCurrencyPair(not to the date effective bits) maybe try selecting the pair instead of attempting to create it every time--or maybe try debugging through a successful new pair to see if a tweak may be needed in the standard service